# NSTrackingArea not fully working when not key window

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsevent, nstrackingarea

A bit of context first. Essentially I have a window that is covering the desktop. On it I have a few WebKit WebView views which allow user interaction. By deafult, as one would expect, when another application is active it does not receive these events (such as hovering, mouse entered, and clicking). I can make it work by clicking my window first, then moving the mouse, but this is not good for usability. I've also managed to make it activate the window when the cursor enters, but it's far from ideal and rather hacky.

So instead I'm trying to use a tracking area. At the moment on the WebViews superview I have this tracking area:

```
NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self visibleRect]
                                                                options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingActiveAlways
                                                                owner:self
                                                                userInfo:nil];
```

This works as I want it to, I'm receiving the all the mouse events. However, the WebViews don't seem to be responding as intended. JavaScript mouse move events only fire when I hold and drag, not just hover and drag.

I've tried using hitTest to get the correct view, but nothing seems to work. Here's an example method, I'm using the isHandlingMouse boolean because without it an infinite loop seemed to be created for some reason:

```
- (NSView *)handleTrackedMouseEvent: (NSEvent *)theEvent{
    if(isHandlingMouse)
        return nil;
    isHandlingMouse = true;
    NSView *hit = [self hitTest: theEvent.locationInWindow];
    if (hit && hit != self) {
        return hit;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSView *hit = [self handleTrackedMouseEvent: theEvent];
    if (hit){
        [hit mouseMoved: theEvent];
    }
    isHandlingMouse = false;
}
```

The 'hit' view, is a WebHTMLView, which appears to be a private class. Everything seems like it should be working,but perhaps there's something I'm doing that's breaking it, or I'm sending the event to the WebHTMLView incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Post a sample Xcode project to make it easier for people to test solutions to this problem.

I was doing something similar and it took a lot of trial and error to find a solution.  You will likely need to subclass NSWindow and add `- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow { return YES; }`, then whenever you detect the mouse is over your window, you might call `[window orderFrontRegardless]` just so it can properly capture the mouse events.